# Map projection from latitude/longitude to cylindrical system

Tags: coordinate-system, mercator, cartesian

I have some questions about projections. First of all, I would like to plot some positions on a x-y grid, graduated in km from latitude/longitudes coordinates. Is this conversion relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection.

If so, is this possible to center the map on an other coordinate than (0,0)? for example, if my coordinates latitudes go from 40 to 50 and my longitude from -5 to 5, can I use (45,0) as a center of my projection? If so, there will be only a few distortions because my point are close from the center of projection?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphsizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Unfortunately while the short form of your four answers ("possibly","yes","yes","very much no") are not long, the long forms would highlight the reason why we don't permit multiple questions in a Question. Please choose your most pressing question, and [Edit] the Question to focus on that.